# XSLT 2.0 how to skip writing to an element when field on input file is null

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I I have a XML input file. I am using xslt to map and write the elements in the input file to a put webservice operation of an application. There are certain elemnts that come without any value (null). I was wondering how to code the condition using xslt such that when there is no value for those column fields, they do not write anything to corresponding mapped element/s or you can say ignore the element/s itself from getting updated.

Here's an example of input file with 3 rows:

Rownum is rownumber, Text2 is let's say SSN and Text3 is Employee ID. If there's employee ID, then the webservice XML has a validation which requires to also update percentage availability to 100 for that employee.

Rownum, Text2, Text3

1,321-99-9999,001

2,,002

3,652-77-7777,

My code looks like this -

```
<xsl:param name='Text2'/>
<xsl:param name='Text3'/>
<xsl:variable name='pct' select='100.00'/>

<SSN>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test= "($Text2!='')">
            <em:em:type="SSN"><xsl:value-of select='$Text2'/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</SSN>      

<Emp>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($Text3!='')">
            <em:Availability><xsl:value-of select="$pct"/></em:Availability>
            <em:ID:em:type="EmpID"><xsl:value-of select='$Text3'/></em:ID>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</Emp>
```

On applying above xslt to input file, rows 1 and 2 get loaded through the webservice but I get a validation error on row 3.

It seems to work fine for Text2 element of the input file. When there is no value in the input file for this element, no update is done to webservice. When there is a value, corresponding update is done to webservice.

For Text3 element which is an employee ID, when there is a value, the element gets updated. Also the availability element, which is percentage, gets updated to 100.

The XSLT fails when there is no Text3 element (no employee ID).
The validation error is thrown stating "Element Content 'Availability' is required, on internal element 'Emp'.

As you can see above, I have used / conditional statement for Text2 and Text3 elements.
When Text2 has null value in the input file, it does not throw any error like I am getting when Text3 element is null. Based on the error message I am guessing it is
the structure of the conditional statement maybe that is not working correctly when Text3 is null. Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"I have a XML input file."* I don't see it. Please post a [mcve] incl. input and expected output. And an XSLT attempt that can be executed - not a snippet taken out of context.

Comment: Please, also provide a real, well-formed XML document, upon which the XSLT transformation is to be applied.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your responses, I overlooked that the conditional construct had to be before the parent node "Emp" so as to apply the condition to both child elements 'Availability' and 'EmpID' when the EmpID was blank. Doing that fixed it.